# “Put my privacy in public” VS. “Share my private information”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

Today while I’m was writing, i wrote a sentence such as:

> - The internet has a negative side because **it can put your privacy in public.

- My native English native teacher corrected me by saying that

> “it can share your private information publicly”
>   And she added that: “we cannot put privacy in public”.

1) What does it make the expression wrong of putting the privacy in public?

2) for me as a non-native English speaker, let’s say, i want to make my **own expression** in English, is it going to be impossible?

Well if it’s impossible, then everything, including the words together compound-words, collocations, should me something i already read from a native English-speaker’s paper or books. Otherwise, I cannot express anything i have in my mind. For instance:

If I didn’t hear English speakers saying, or  English speakers writing “we share private information publicly” instead of saying “put my privacy in public”, then my ability would be forever limited of expressing myself. (Advice)

---

**Note**:The second point of my question is sort of off-topic. However, you answer to it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Privacy" is by the dictionary "a state in which one is not observed or disturbed by other people."  It is an abstract noun,  so it cannot be "in public". Privacy doesn't mean "private information", it means "the state of being free from public attention".

A person can be in public view. Information about a person can be in public. But the *meaning* of "privacy" is not compatible with something being in pubic.

You can, of course, make your own expressions in English.  In this case, you simply didn't understand the meaning of the word "privacy". In the general case: please make up lots of original English sentences. You will make lots of mistakes and learn by them. The only thing that is impossible is to learn English while never making a mistake.